# How to dedicate user to single session host server

Tags: remote-desktop

In my environment, I've 10 session host servers and 400 users that'll be going to connect. I have a requirement of 10 users should have different session host servers at all the time. and the rest of 390 users can have any session host servers out of 10session hosts. Is there any way of dedicating these users a separate host server when they RDP\RDWeb access. Kindly share your views and suggestion. I sincerely appreciate your thoughts and answers

FYI
RDS setup has done on Windows server 2012
Gateways servers   2
Broker 1
Session host servers 10.

RDS is in working state not in production though

Comment: is anyone there??

Comment: Your question does not actually say what system you are using or what you are attempting to do. The only tag was "RDS" -- I'm assuming that means "Remote Desktop"? Feel free to edit your question and tags to better explain what you are trying to do and people might then be able to assist.

Comment: you can assume "RDS" means "Remote Desktop Services" and in the description, I mentioned Windows server 2012. I guess.  Feel free to ask more questions